This or that in this context?
I am coming to Belgium next week ,I arrive on Monday . Will your shop be open on  Thursday 25th  April  or are you going to a record fair this day ?
Can I use this day instead of that day to emphasize the importance of the date even if this date is far from now

That day is far more natural, and is not 'less emphatic'.

When reading the sentence, that day sounds far more natural. This day sounds like someone is directly translating an expression from another language which is not idiomatic in English.
The rules about "this" and "that" are varied, but often  "this" refers to something close by, while "that" indicates an object further away. At times  either word is appropriate.
A distant day is "that day".
When can you use "this day"?

There is a common phrase "On this day in History", when discussing events throughout the years that occurred on the same date as today.

If you were looking at a physical calendar and put your finger on a date, it could be "this day".

There is a phrase in the dictionary "to this day" as in "The belief persists to this day".  In that context "this day" means "today".

Perhaps if there is a long ongoing discussion about a particular "day", which is repeatedly being mentioned, it might eventually be called "this day" in certain situations.


Beyond the list of compiled exceptions (I might be missing some) a regular day (not today) is "that day".

If you'd like to emphasis the date, it's possible to say "that exact day?", or "that particular day?", or a similar construction. However in the example you provided I would not recommend it.
